# No such file or directory in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

My bash script. After its completion, it receives `line 9: 1570066642: No such file or directory`

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date "+%s")

while read p; do

IFS=',' read -ra my_array <<< "$p"

if [ "${my_array[1]}" < "${DATE}" ] ; then
    continue
fi

echo "$p" >> my_file.txt

done <cache_data.txt

mv my_file.txt cache_data.txt
```

I want to check the difference between dates in timestamp seconds.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `((` for arithmetic operations.

```
if ((${my_array[1]} < DATE)); then
```

If you do use `[` then you need to change `<` to `-lt`. Unlike `((`, `[` is not special shell syntax. It is just a regular command with an unusual single character name, which means that the shell interprets `<` as a file redirection rather than a less than operator.

```
if [ "${my_array[1]}" -lt "${DATE}" ] ; then
```

---

You can simplify the `read` calls. Instead of reading a whole line and then calling `read` a second time to parse the comma-separated fields you can do both at once.

You also don't need to read the results into an array. `read` can assign to multiple variables at once.

Finally, if you hoist the `>> my_file.txt` redirection out of the loop you can avoid opening and closing the file every iteration, a nice optimization.

```
while IFS=',' read -r field1 timestamp rest_of_line; do
    ((timestamp >= DATE)) || continue
    echo "$field1 $timestamp"
done <cache_data.txt >my_file.txt
```

I like to use `&&` and `||` as shorthand for `if` and `if !`. They're a common shell scripting idiom for quick tests. I've used `||` above to demonstrate. You may find that more or less readable. Opinions vary.